# Show total no. rows for in HTML <span>

Tags: javascript, html

I need your help in displaying the total number of rows for the available tables in the appropriate span. There are 3 tables and I want the below code to show the total no. of rows in the first table in span1 & the total no. of rows for the second table in span2. 
The JavaScript is:

```
function count() {        
    var tables = document.getElementsByClassName("tablesorter");        
    var rows;        
    var span = Array();                 

    for (var i = 0; i < tables.length; i++) {        
        rows = tables[i].rows.length-1;        
        alert(rows);        
        alert(span[i]);        
        span[i].innerHTML = rows;        
    }

}
```

However, `span[i]` is not picking up the value and print it in the HTML `span`.
The HTML code is:

```
<body>
    <span id="span1"></span>
    <span id="span2"></span>
    <span id="span3"></span>
</body>
```

I am looking forward your assistant and help.

Comment: where are you referring those `spans` you have created a new array called `span` and you are changing that.

Comment: Do you have some idea that you can do `span[i]` and use that to reference the span called `span1` (if `i` is 1)? That isn't possible. Other than that I'm not clear on what you're trying to do.

Comment: Is it the right way to print the values in the appropriate spans?

Comment: @JacobMattison What I want is that the for loop will get the values of the total rows count in each table and I want them to be printed accordingly in the span, the first table value should be in span1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this function instead:

```
function count() {

    var tables = document.getElementsByClassName("tablesorter");

    var rows;

    for (var i = 0; i < tables.length; i++) {

        rows = tables[i].rows.length-1;

        alert(rows);

        document.getElementById("span" + (i + 1)).innerHTML = rows;

    }
}
```

You are never referring to the span, so that is why I used

```
document.getElementById("span" + (i + 1)).innerHTML = rows;
```